# ¿Cómo reproducir automaticamente un audio con la etiqueta AUDIO?

Tags: javascript, html

Saludos a toda la comunidad. Estoy realizando un pequeño reproductor de audio y quiero que se reproduzca automaticamente al cargar la pagina. El problema es que no lo hace, tengo que presionar el botón y ya empieza a reproducirse.

Aqui el codigo html:

```
<div>
    <audio id="testAudio" autoplay>
      <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/music/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio>
<button id="playAudio"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
</div>
```

aqui el codigo de javaScript:

```
 <script>
   window.onload = function() {
  var context = new AudioContext();
}
    document.getElementById("playAudio").addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log('clickkk')
      var audio = document.getElementById('testAudio');
    if(this.className == 'is-playing'){
      this.className = "";
      this.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-play'></i>"
      audio.pause();
    }else{
      this.className = "is-playing";
      this.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-pause'></i>";
      audio.play();
    }

  });
  </script>
```

Alguna idea de cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: Amigo, la pregunta no tiene una respuesta valida a mi parecer, ya que según tengo entendido, para bien de la comunidad que usa un explorador, no puedes  reproducir un elemento audio al cargarse la pagina, para poder que ocurra debe ocurrir antes alguna acción que el usuario haya hecho, como por ejemplo darle click al boton play del audio o recargar la pagina con f5 o con el boton de refresh.

Comment: Si ingresas directamente a la pagina no te reproducira un elemento audio automaticamente ni aunque este elemento tuviese el atributo autoplay puesto, (Hablo en el caso de chrome), en el caso de firefox, puede que te reproduzca el audio al incio de la carga de la pagina, pero no todas las vecez, y en opera no he probado.

Comment: Ahora que recuerdo, si no estoy mal, si dejas visibles los controles del elemento audio, en navegadores no muy actualizados te funcionara a la perfeccion, (eso si le pones el atributo controls a la etiqueta audio te lo permite), luego si quieres podrias ocultar el elemento audio con css utilizando la propiedad visibility de css

Comment: Cabe resaltar que cuando digo 'se requiere una acción previa para que se reproduzca el audio', no necesariamente me refiero a que si o si le tienes que dar al boton play del audio o debes recargar la pagina con f5 o el boton refresh de los navegadores, con esto me refiero a cualquier listener activable por el usuario, por ejemplo eventos tipo click, tipo scroll, tipo drag pueden activar el audio (Para ello debes extraer el elemento audio en javascript y realizar esa acción de ponerle play al audio desde algun listener).